# How can I serve up HTML and JSON with nginx during "maintenance mode"?

Tags: php, nginx

I've got an nginx config for a PHP web app and I would like to make it serve an additional purpose, and I can't seem to find a way to accomplish it. My current nginx config does the following:

- Rewrites `/` and `/intro/*` to static HTML pages for a non-PHP powered "marketing" site
- Attempts to load `/maintenance.html` if present on disk, which only exists during deploys
- If `/maintenance.html` does not exist, sends requests to PHP via FastCGI

The end result is that the static pages remain available during deploys, and the back end PHP app can go down for maintenance while deploys happen. The important portion of the `server` config block looks like:

```
rewrite ^/$ /marketing/index.html last;
rewrite ^/intro/(.*)$ /marketing/$1.html last;

try_files $uri /maintenance.html @webapp;
location @webapp
{
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 last;
}

include php.conf;
```

(`php.conf` config handles `location ~ \.php$` locations and does all the usual `fastcgi_param` setting. Nothing project-specific there, so I didn't post that block.)

What I would like to be able to do in addition to the above is when "maintenance mode" is on, serve up `/maintenance.html` for standard HTTP requests, but respond with some JSON when handling AJAX requests. I've found that I can safely return rudimentary content by doing:

```
if ($http_x_requested_with = XMLHttpRequest)
{
    return 503 '{"maintenance":true}';
}
```

However, this obviously happens for *all* requests, not just those where `/maintenance.html` is being served.  It seems I will need some flag somewhere, since `try_files` doesn't let you do additional things depending on which file or location it selected.

Is there some way nginx can be configured to return both HTML and JSON maintenance mode details?

**Edit:** Thinking about it more, it would be nice to perhaps move `maintenance.html` out of `try_files` completely, so that it can be served with a 503 status instead of a 200.

Comment: I'm very interested in this too - We have a similar situation, except it's with an Express server for a prototype application. It has a few html endpoints for whitebox-style viewing, but the primary routers are JSON API style endpoints.

I've been trying to figure out a way to have nginx return standard error pages for html, and then a standard JSON response for any POST requests with the json content-type, but I've had no luck so far.

If you have any tips on how to do this, I'm very keen to hear!